# JavaScript DOM Issue

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having trouble retrieving the textContent of some of my elements. The issue arises from line 88-91. Line 91 retrieves a value of null. I don't understand why this is so. I was able to verify this by setting line 91 to a variable and console.log() to the console and the value was returned as null. Additionally, at line 99 my console is giving me an error of, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined". I'm assuming this error is related to the issue I'm having at lines 88-91, but I'm not entirely sure because it says undefined and not null. The HTML elements have text inside of them so I don't know why it would be returning null. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for you guys insight!

HTML Markup:

```js
(function(){
        const taskList = document.querySelector('ul');
        const completedList = document.querySelector('#completed-task');
        const editTask = document.querySelector('#edit-task');
        const cover = document.querySelector('.cover');
        const editedInfo = document.querySelector('#edited-info');
        const editedDate = document.querySelector('#edited-date');
        const editedName = document.querySelector('edited-item');
        let editedListItem;
    
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            /* Preventing Page Default Page Refresh*/
            e.preventDefault();
        
            /* Grabbing User Input */
            let userInput = document.querySelector('input').value;
            let userDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
            let userInfo = document.getElementById('userInfo').value;
        
            /* Creating Elements */
            let listItem = document.createElement('li');
            let container = document.createElement('div');
            let item = document.createElement('span');
            let deletebutton = document.createElement('span');
            /* Update: February 4, 2019 --> Creating Info Box */
            let infoBox = document.createElement('div');
            let dueDate = document.createElement('p');
            let info = document.createElement('p');
            let span = document.createElement('span');
            /* Update: February 5, 2019 --> Creating Edit button */
            let edit = document.createElement('span');
    
            /* Adding Attributes */
            container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
            deletebutton.setAttribute('class','delete');
            infoBox.setAttribute('class','info');
            edit.setAttribute('class', 'edit');
    
            /* Setting User Input */
            item.textContent = userInput;
            span.textContent = userDate;
            info.textContent = userInfo;
            deletebutton.textContent = "Discard";
            dueDate.textContent = "Due: ";
            edit.textContent = "Edit";
            
    
            /* Adding Elements to List */
            taskList.appendChild(listItem);
            listItem.appendChild(container);
            container.appendChild(item);
            container.appendChild(deletebutton);
            listItem.appendChild(infoBox);
            infoBox.appendChild(dueDate);
            infoBox.appendChild(info);
            dueDate.appendChild(span);
            infoBox.appendChild(edit);
        });
    
        document.querySelector('#task-list').addEventListener('click',function(event){
            if(event.target.className == 'delete') {
                const li = event.target.parentElement;
                li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
            }
        });
    
        /* Update: February 4, 2019 --> Hide Tasks Checkbox */
        document.forms['hide-task'].addEventListener('change', function(event){
            const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                
            if (checkbox.checked === true) {
                taskList.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                taskList.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    
        taskList.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            if (event.target.className == 'complete') {
                let parent = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
                completedList.appendChild(parent);
            }
   

    /******* ISSUE OCCURS IN THIS CODE BLOCK *************/
                if (event.target.className == 'edit') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    editTask.style.display = 'flex';
                    cover.style.display = 'block';
                    editedDate.value = event.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.textContent;
                    editedInfo.value = event.target.previousSibling.textContent;
                    editedName.value = event.target.parentElement.previousSibling.firstChild.textContent;
                    editedListItem = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
                }
            });
        
            document.querySelector('#change').addEventListener('click', function(event){
        
                editedListItem.firstChild.firstChild.textContent = editedName.value;
                editedListItem.lastChild.firstChild.textContent = editedDate.value;
                editedListItem.lastChild.lastChild.textContent = editedInfo.value;
                
                editTask.style.display = 'none';
                cover.style.display = 'none';
            });
        
        })()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">       
        <title>To Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <h1>To do List</h1>
        <form>
            <div id="input-button">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item..." class="item">
                <button type="submit" class="add">&#43;</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Due Date..." id="date">
                <input type="text" placeholder="About the task..." id="userInfo">
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <ul id="task-list">
            <li>
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="title">Example Task</span>
                    <span class="delete">Discard</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Update: Feb #, 2019 --> 
                <div class="info">
                    <p>Due: <span>January 15, 2019</span></p>
                    <p>This is some example text that adds additional context or information for the task</p>
                    <span class="edit">Edit</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Update: February 5, 2019 -->
        <ul id="completed-task">
            <li id="title">Completed Tasks</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Update: February 4, 2019 -->
        <form id="hide-task">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hide-task">
                <label for="hide-task">Hide Tasks</label>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form id="edit-task">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Edit item..." id="edited-item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Edit Due Date..." id="edited-date">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Edit about the task..." id="edited-info">
            <button id="change" type="button">Change</button>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: One issue is that `editedListItem` is `undefined` within `#change` `click` handler. `editedListItem` is not defined until `taskList` `click` event.

Comment: Hey guest271314, I'm not sure I understand. The taskList click event should fire before the user gets a chance to fire the #change.  Wouldn't that resolve the undefined problem of editedListItem?

Comment: What do you mean by _"before the user gets a chance to fire the #change"_? What prevents a user from clicking the button labeled "Change"? The input fields are not required at HTML. Even if `taskList` is clicked first if `if (event.target.className == 'edit'){}` does not evaluate to `true`, `editedListItem` will still not be defined.

Comment: Thank you for looking through my code for the bug. I have display: none; applied to the form with id="edit-task" so the user can't click on the change button until they click on the word edit. Once edit is clicked the CSS rule changes to display: flex; and the form "edit-task" can then be used by the user. If they click on edit the if statement should evaluate to true because of the event.target.className grabs the class name of the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a break and some dinner, I started debugging with a fresh set of eyes and an unfrustrated mind and found the bugs. Everything is now working properly.

**1st Issue:**
     A Typo in the querySelector was responsible for one of the variables to return 
     textContent error.

**Solution:**

```
const editedName = document.querySelector('#edited-item');
```

**2nd Issue:**
    For the most part `previousSibling` and `previousElementSibling` return the element, but
    `previousSibling` will return any kind of sibling. Some browsers add white space around
    the elements and so `previousSibling` will grab the white space around the element 
    instead, but `previousElementSibling` always grabs the Element. My initial code was
    grabbing the white space around the element.

**Solution:**

```
    taskList.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (event.target.className == 'complete') {
        let parent = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        completedList.appendChild(parent);
    }

    if (event.target.className == 'edit') {
        event.preventDefault();
        editTask.style.display = 'flex';
        cover.style.display = 'block';
        editedDate.value = event.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.textContent;
        editedInfo.value = event.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        editedName.value = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.textContent;
        editedListItem = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    }
});

document.querySelector('#change').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    editedListItem.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.textContent = editedName.value;
    editedListItem.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.textContent = editedDate.value;
    editedListItem.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.textContent = editedInfo.value;

    editTask.style.display = 'none';
    cover.style.display = 'none';
});
```